# Find the following integral in terms of its parameters

Tags: calculus, integration

If I have $$\int_0^\infty {1\over u^2}{e^{-au^2+bu-c\over ku}} du$$ where $a,b,c,k\in \mathbb{R}_+$.

Is there a way to get an explicit formula in terms of the constants? Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Try $t=-\frac{au}{k}-\frac{c}{ku}$ as a substitution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integral is
$$ 2\,{\frac {\sqrt {a}}{\sqrt {c}}{{\rm e}^{{ {b}/{k}}}}{{\rm K}_{1}
\left(2\,{\frac {\sqrt {ac}}{k}}\right)}}
$$ where $K_1$ is a [modified Bessel function of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1).

Answer (score 0):

WA says this here:
$\text{ConditionalExpression}\left[2 \sqrt{\frac{a}{k}}
   e^{b/k} \sqrt{\frac{k}{c}} K_1\left(\frac{2
   \sqrt{\frac{a}{k}}}{\sqrt{\frac{k}{c}}}\right),
\Re\left(\frac{a}{k}\right)>0\land
   \Re\left(\frac{c}{k}\right)>0\right]$